# Proof regarding operator norm.

Tags: calculus, normed-spaces

Let $(V,\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert_V),(W,\left\Vert \cdot\right\Vert_W) $ be norm spaces.

For any linear transformation $\;T:V\rightarrow W\;$ we will define:$\;\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{op}=sup\{\left\Vert Tv\right\Vert _{W}:\left\Vert v\right\Vert _{V}=1\}$

Show that:

$\forall c\geq0$ , $\;\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{op}\leq c\;$ $\iff \left\Vert Tx\right\Vert _{W}\leq c\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{V}\;\; \forall x \in V$

edit: This is what I tried:

For $\impliedby$:

We have that $\left\Vert Tx\right\Vert _{W}\leq c\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{V}\;\; \forall x \in V$, specifically for any $x \in V$ such that $\left\Vert x\right\Vert _{V} = 1$, therefore we get from homogeniety : $c\geq sup\{\left\Vert Tv\right\Vert _{W}:\left\Vert v\right\Vert _{V}=1\} = \;\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{op}$

Since $\;\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{op}\geq 0$ we get from transitivty that $c\geq 0$

For $\implies$:
I tried by contradiction, which means that I assume that $\forall c\geq0$ , $\;\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{op}\leq c\;$ but there exists $x_0\in V$ such that
$\left\Vert Tx_0\right\Vert _{W}> c\left\Vert x_0\right\Vert _{V}$

We know that $\frac{x_{0}}{\left\Vert x_{0}\right\Vert _{\text{V}}}$ is a unit vector in $V$. 
Therefore:
$\left\Vert T\right\Vert _{op}\geq\left\Vert T(\frac{x_{0}}{\left\Vert x_{0}\right\Vert _{\text{V}}})\right\Vert _{W}=\frac{1}{\left\Vert x_{0}\right\Vert _{V}}\left\Vert Tx_{0}\right\Vert _{W}>c\frac{1}{\left\Vert x_{0}\right\Vert _{V}}\left\Vert x_{0}\right\Vert _{V}=c$

Which gives us a contradiction

Comment: Is $\leftarrow$ obvious to you at least? Use the definition of $||\cdot||_{\mbox{op}}$. For the other you need to think. Have you done that? What did you come up with?

Comment: We can take any unit vector from $V$ and apply homogenity?

Comment: This isn't a free homework site.

Comment: Yes, somewhat. Can you write an answer below, if you are confident of your suggestion? Be more detailed than "homogeniety". Be sure to write both directions.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I am sorry, I really tried solving this one.

Comment: @vpam We understand that, but only once you said it. Remember, if you had included your attempts (like your comment above) in the post before posting it, you would have attracted more attention and got maybe better answers. But you can proceed to put your answer down. I have seen that you worked on the MathJax, so good about that.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Added. thanks for understanding

Comment: Great. Now the answer below will be helpful to you. I will sleep now, so I'll see you in the morn if you have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $ x/||x||$ has norm 1 and the linearity of T.

EDIT: $||T||=\text{inf}\{ c\geq 0: ||T(x)|| \leq c||x|| \;\text{for all} \; x \in V\} $

Proof: I am going to suppose the above is finite, the second case is easier in my opinion (try it).

Suppose ||T|| is finite then, $$ ||T||=  \text{inf}\{c\geq 0: ||T(x)|| \leq c||x||\; \text{for all}\;x \}, \\ = \text{inf}\{ c \geq 0: \left|\left|T\left(\frac{x}{||x||}\right)\right|\right| \leq c,\; ||x|| \neq 0\}\cup \{0\}, \\ = \text{inf}\{c \geq 0: ||T(y)|| \leq c, \; ||y||=1 \}.$$

The above set is the set of upper bounds of $\{ ||T(x) ||: ||x||=1\}$ therefore it’s infinum is the lowest upper bound I.e the supremum.

Comment: Mind taking a look?

Comment: @vpam yeah sure